# Rails "No Route" when the rake routes shows it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, param

I'm getting a `No route matches [DELETE] "/users"` when rake routes shows:

```
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)         users#show
     PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)         users#update
     PUT    /users/:id(.:format)         users#update
     DELETE /users/:id(.:format)         users#destroy
```

In my view I have this link and path:

```
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user_path(user, :id => user.email), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

As you can see above, I'm sending an `id` param.

I can fix this by adding this to routes:

```
delete 'users' => 'users#destroy'
```

But then when I check `params` in the controller, it has no `id` attribute. I have also tried

```
delete 'users/:id' => 'users#destroy'
```

Here's what the params look like:

```
{"_method"=>"delete", "authenticity_token"=>"r81EQsF0z2eoIUTIrc3Rd2pQlVRNL6iEcM58DzkkOWCeLg+LLudBwhVvSyM7DTRXm2EGvKaMwCT+orbG8YDuOg==", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"destroy"}
```

Comment: Does your user have a nil email? Why pass email rather than id?

Answer (score 0):

The route `"/users"` doesn't exist and shouldn't. `"/users"` is not the same as `"/users/:id"`

In your routes.rb file, to enable CRUD actions on users you should have

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  resources :users
end
```

Amongst others, the above line is interpreted by rails as

```
delete 'users/:id', to: "users#destroy"
```

Here the `:id` is part of the route name. So the path helper that is generated takes one argument. Here the method name user_path generates the url `users/`, and the first parameter is used to determine the rest `:id`

If you don't want to identify resources by their ID, then the resource syntax is quite confusing. I'd rather do something like that

```
delete 'users/:email', to: 'users#destroy', as: 'delete_user'
```

and you can call the helper like this

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', delete_user_path(user.email), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Note that in your controller you'll have to change the way you set the user

```
@user = User.find(params[:email])
```

Comment: I get that, but I am overriding the id in my database. I have `resources :users` in my routes file. if I add the `route` loop I get a syntax error. also `delete users/:id, to: "users#destroy"` throws a syntax error

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited. the routes do was a reference to the very first line of the file. What do you mean "I am overriding the id" ?

Comment: adding `delete 'users/:id', to: "users#destroy"` to the routes file is the same thing as `resources :users` it just makes two entries in rake routes. in this case it still throws an `route not found` error. and again, I am overriding the `id` parameter

Comment: The problem is the way you use the path helper. Don't use `user_path(user, id: ...)` but `user_path(user.email)` if you need to identify users by email

Comment: I believe you are on the correct route, however now when I submit Destroy it just redirects to index.html.erb?

Comment: it turns out I needed to specify `:method => :delete` but now I'm getting the same `No route matches [DELETE] "/users"` even though rake routes is showing I do

Comment: Have you tried <%= link_to 'Destroy', {:action => "destroy :id => user.id), :method => :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %> ? Can you confirm what's in your routes file? You may want to first see if you can get it working passing the id param and then try passing the email.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the action 'destroy' to your view to match it to the RESTFUL verb. Presumably you do mean to pass the email as the id parameter?

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', {:action => "destroy :id => user.email), :method => :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Comment: still doesn't send the id param

Comment: Sorry forgot to add, you need to include the method as well.